# Reverse proxy of a WEB server when adding ssl certificate does not work css and js

Tags: web-services, nginx, proxy, certbot

Friends, I'm trying to create a reverse proxy on a server with NGINX, of course the proxy works fine, but since I don't have a certificate on my website and unfortunately the hosting company doesn't allow me to generate a certificate without my domain pointing to their DNS servers .

Returning to the explanation, when validating the certificate, my proxy is without the css and js of the site, I don't know if I need to use some specific parameter, my configuration is this:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom_proxy.conf directory
server {

server_name mydomain1.com;

location / {

```
   proxy_pass http://mydomain2.com;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_buffering off;
```

}
}

My proxy server is from oracle and my website is on a hosting company.

my objective is:

to the user type https://mydomain1.com
it is redirected to https://mydomain2.com

when redirected, he will navigate normally through the site, with all the functionalities and with a valid certificate, thank you in advance, sorry if the explanation is not very good